# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'method' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Есть модуль:

```js
async function request(url, { method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {} }) {
    console.log(method)
    let loading = false;
    let error = null;
    let data = null;
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, { method, body, headers });
        const data_ = await response.json();
        data = data_;
        loading = true;
    } catch (err) {
        error = err.message;
        loading = true;
    }

    return { loading, data, error }
}

export default request;
```

```js
const topNews = request('http://localhost:5500/api/news/top/2');
```

Почему-то при вызове `request()` выдает ошибку:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'method' of undefined

Comment: `request('...', {})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже если вы задаёте параметры по умолчанию в деструктурировании, функция не сможет деструктурировать отсутствующий объект. Есть два решения.

1. Передать пустой объект в аргументе:

```js
const topNews = request('http://localhost:5500/api/news/top/2', {});
```

2. Задать пустой объект по умолчанию в параметре:

```js
async function request(url, { method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {} } = {}) {
```